# crop an image along the edges using opencv

Tags: python-2.7, opencv

Can someone help me on how to crop an image along the edges using OpenCV? Searching only gives results on how to crop along the rectangular edge. I need to crop it along the edge of an image, ie, if it is an image of an apple, I need to crop the image along the edge of the apple. Is it possible?

Comment: Images, in OpenCV and elsewhere, only have *one* width and *one* height so they are necessarily rectangular and could only follow the outline of an apple if it too was rectangular. What were you hoping for?

Answer (score 0):

```
import cv2
img = cv2.imread("lenna.png")
crop_img = img[200:400, 100:300] # Crop from x, y, w, h -> 100, 200, 300, 400
# NOTE: its img[y: y + h, x: x + w] and *not* img[x: x + w, y: y + h]
cv2.imshow("cropped", crop_img)
cv2.waitKey(0)
```

Above you have an example for cropping image in python 2 using OpenCV